# Sort favorites by number of answers and stars

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, sorting, usability, favorites-tab

The favorites tab includes the following columns:

- Star count
- Votes
- Answers
- Views
- Content

The list is sortable by Votes and Views. It would be great if it were also sortable by Answers and Star count. This would make it easier to go back to unanswered questions to provide an answer and to revisit popular questions with personal relevance.

Comment: You seem to have favourited a large proportion of highly voted questions... if you're not actually going to use the answers or don't believe that the questions are _that_ interesting have you considered unfavouriting some of them?

Comment: Sorry, links are my addiction of choice.

Comment: That's fine :-); we all have our own... my guess would be that you're in a small minority, as posited by Austin, which makes this less likely to be implemented but if you want all the links then I can quite understand why you'd like better sorting for them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature request may be useful (probably for a smaller number of users) but personally I only favorite a handful of questions. Once you start favoriting a large number of posts then it some what defeats the purpose of this feature. Instead of favoriting you could always just search!

However, if this is not added then you can always use [data.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to do the sorting for you! (the queries you want may already exist)

Comment: [Here's the query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/91413/my-favorites-data)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a couple of queries in data.SE for the aforementioned purposes:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/158282/filter-favorites-by-tag-name

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/137288/sorted-favorites

Hope this is useful for future reference.